# Show modal when user try to reupload file in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to show a modal when user try to reupload file in shiny, I want to alert user, but the modal always appear after the fileupload finished, and it seem that when I first upload file, the modal still appear, it shouldn't happend.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file", "Choose a CSV file", accept = ".csv"),
  actionButton("read", "Read CSV"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    if (!is.null(input$file)) {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Replace",
        "You have uploaded a file now, do you want to replace it?",
        footer = tagList(
          actionButton("replace", "Yes", class = "btn-danger"),
          modalButton("Cancel")
        )
      ))
    }
  })
  observeEvent(input$replace, {
    removeModal()
  })
  observeEvent(input$read, {
    mydata(read.csv(input$file$datapath))
  })
  output$table <- renderTable({
    mydata()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a Shiny modal I don't know (I think this is not possible). Here is a way with a sweet alert.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.10.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"),
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.10.0/dist/sweetalert2.min.css"),
    tags$script(src = "swal01.js")
  ),
  br(),
  fileInput("upload", "Upload")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

File ***swal01.js***, to put in the ***www*** subfolder:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var upload = false;
  $("#upload").on("click", async function(event) {
    if(!upload) {
      upload = true;
      return true;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    const { value: yes } = await Swal.fire({
      title: "Do you want to upload a new file?",
      showDenyButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: "Yes",
      denyButtonText: "No"
    });
    if(yes) {
      upload = false;
      $("#upload").click();
    }
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: I almost know nothing about JS and I was wondering if I want to achieve this in 10 fileInputs, should I repeat the above code 10 times, replacing only their id?

Comment: @toxin or you can use arrays and a loop